# How does the setTimeout() in javascript knows how many times to loop inside of a for loop?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, ecmascript-2016

```js
for (var index = 1; index <= 3; index++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('after ' + index + ' second(s):' + index);
  }, index * 1000);
}
```

```
 output:

 after 4 second(s):4
 after 4 second(s):4
 after 4 second(s):4
 after 4 second(s):4
```

I understand using "let" instead of "var" solves this problem, but my question is, how in the world does the callback function inside the setTimeout function knows to run 4 times given the execution of setTimeout starts after the loop is completed?

This is more of educated question and trying to better understand the problem with follow up questions. I can't figure out how the setTimeout function knows how many times to run the callback function.

Comment: You called `setTimeout()` 4 times. Each call started an independent timer.

Comment: Actually only 3 times. I don't see how you're getting that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `console.log()` outside `setTimeout` you will find the reason

```js
for (var index = 1; index <= 3; index++) {
    // it will execute this line 3 times,then begin to invoke console.log inside setTimeout
    console.log("before: " + index) 
    setTimeout(function () {
       console.log('after ' + index + ' second(s):' + index);
    }, index * 1000);
 }
```

Comment: I get it now, thanks for turning on my smart switch. I can't believe this flew over my head.